# Resaving Matrix Blocks skips because of "not loading its content"

Tags: matrix, craft4, cli

We recently updated one of our biggest projects to Craft 4. And today I tried to resave all the matrix block with `resave/matrix-blocks` but was greeted with the following behaviour:

[image]

Does anybody have a similar problem or know what might cause this? Using the CP works expected without any problems. And the logs don't show me anything to work with.

Leonardo

Comment: I cant't remeber how we solved this issue. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [the official docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/console-commands.html#resave-matrix-blocks), the `resave/matrix-blocks` command needs the `--field` (i.e. a Matrix field handle) or `--element-id` (IDs of specific blocks to resave) arguments, on order for Craft to pull in the correct content tables.

This means that you won't be able to resave all Matrix blocks in a single command, but have to them field by field, i.e.

```shell
./craft resave/matrix-blocks --field matrixFieldHandle
```

...where `matrixFieldHandle` should be replaced with an actual Matrix field handle.